# Code dumps/too localized

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

So I came across these questions (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58168/java-animation-memory-overload + https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58167/animation-color) and I don't see how the close options cover too localized situations or code dumps.

```
duplicate
```

Too localized to be a duplicate.

```
off-topic
```

Probably would be better on SO than here but either way I want to close it not get it migrated to a place that would instantly close it.

```
unclear what you're asking
```

It is obvious what is being asked.

```
too broad
```

This is exactly what the question isn't

```
primarily opinion-based
```

Nope there is a single absolule answer.

So I know people were not a fan of Too Localized but it seems to fit perfectly here. But anyways my question is with the current close options which ones are best suited to code dumps? The changes seemed to focus around better feedback to the user about closures so it seems odd that telling them "we're not here to debug your code" by saying its off topic.

Comment: Off topic includes subcategories that can be optionally specified.  http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/off-topic-variations

Comment: @Tetrad In other words the transition to the new system isn't over and the close options are going to change? Anyways I don't like how things not related to being off topic are going to be under off topic. The point of all of the changes seem to be better feedback and stashing "pls debug my code" under off topic kinda goes against that.

Comment: Off topic means "outside the scope of the site".  Custom options can say whatever we want, which could include "code dumps are not welcome" or whatever.

Comment: @Tetrad However [you said that there is only room for three options](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/1214/2158) and "too localized" is not among your suggestions or the current list. I would really like to have [what Seth suggested](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/1181/2158)

Comment: Does GameDev have "Off-Topic" -> "Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it *should* work."?  If not perhaps it should as this exactly describes both of these questions and includes advice on how they need improving (tell us what you tried)

Comment: Agreed; GD is a site where this is appropriate; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons ("*Today, TL is used helpfully on code dump questions on SO, but the new OT reasons are where this is now correctly addressed.*").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Observation:  Today, code-dump questions are being closed as "Too broad" where previously we were closing them as "Too localised".  As I type this, there are four code-dump questions in the review queue.  Each of these have attracted several "Too broad" votes, and no other votes.

I guess the mental logic behind voting code-dump as too broad goes something like this:  "you're not focusing down onto a specific question, you're just throwing code at us".  And that makes sense to me.  But that's not what the "Too broad" close-reason shows to a user whose question has been closed;  that notification says:

**"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."**

That's got to be confusing to a user who's just trying to solve a problem they're having;  it doesn't explain what's actually wrong with their question or what they need to do to make a better question that will actually get an answer.  We don't actually want them to add details -- we want them to diagnose their problem to the point where they have an actual question, not merely a cry of befuddlement at their specific code.

Personally, I'd be much happier with an OT reason explicitly for code-dump questions, as they do make up a pretty sizable chunk of our questions which get closed.

Comment: +1 For a specific off-topic close reason for those questions. The notification could be along the lines of: "Large chunks of code without a definite question are hard to answer by anyone else than yourself. You should try to use a [debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) or simple print statements to trace your variables. Please try spotting your issue more precisely and editing your post to formulate an actual question."