# Does game design questions being on topic and opinion based being off-topic contradict?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

Well my concern was raised when I saw [this meta thread](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/why-is-there-no-voting-for-closing-or-holding-questions) about a game design question being closed. Even though I agree the question is off topic and was asking for opinions.

I find that most game design questions are opinion based in the first (which is also a big factor of why we have average and great games) My only concern is that game design questions being primarily opinion based are not fit for this site, which make it less useful. But I still think we can address them in a way that they become on-topic questions, How do you think we can address them other than closing?

Comment: Related prior discussions are [here](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/978/is-this-the-site-for-game-design-related-questions) and [here](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/903/game-design-questions-should-we-be-more-lax-with-regard-to-ses-question-answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["Good subjective" is okay, "bad subjective" is not](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). I think it's more difficult to ask a question that is game design focused that is a "good" subjective question, but it has been done and continues to be done.

I will reiterate again that having a question put on hold is *not a punishment* and so if voting to close is the proper solution to an inappropriate question for the site, *do it*.

That said, there is another recourse available to you. If you see an inappropriate question and believe it can be salvaged, *edit it* and make it salvageable. That's why the edit privilege exists. If you lack the privilege to edit or to vote to close, flag it.

The only *incorrect* thing to do with an inappropriate question on this, or any other StackExchange site, is to do nothing.